# How can I execute an SQLite statement in C++

Tags: c++, windows, linux, sqlite

I have the following command which works fine on Linux Console. But to get the result to a cpp file I have to store it to file and then read it. But is there a way I can directly execute this command in C++.

```
/usr/bin/sqlite3 /etc/myDB/db/share.db "select path from folder_info where ftp='YES'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i understand your question you can use the SQLite3 c++ api which is described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html)

Comment: You can also check this demo project (it`s for windows, but it will get the overall idea) - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CppSQLite.aspx

Comment: You can also use the C API into sqlite from C++.

Answer (score 1):

> **How can I execute an SQLite statement in C++**

using [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)

[An Introduction To The SQLite C/C++ Interface](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html)

```
    sqlite3 *db; 
    sqlite3_open("dbfile.db", &db);
    sqlite3_stmt *companydetails;
    std::stringstream companystr;
    companystr << "select companyname,companydetails from company";
    sqlite3_prepare(db, companystr.str().c_str(), companystr.str().size(),&companydetails, NULL);
    sqlite3_step(companydetails);
```